# How to populate CollectionView Horizontally with an Array Model that is coming from API

Tags: swift

I am having a lot of difficulties dealing with setting up the `CollectionView` in the `ViewController` to populate the `CollectionView Cells` with the `Model` I have.

The `CollectionView` needs to be Horizontally, I tried setting it up like i did with `tableView cells` but it's a different world the one of the `CollectionView` since I can't work it out like `tableView` just a simple list since in `CollectionView Horizontally` it's in form of left-right not in a form of list

Any little help is really appreciated.

My Model:

```
struct connectedProperties: Decodable {
   var StatusCode: Int
   var Result: [connProperties]?
}

struct connProperties: Decodable {
   let id: Int
   let completeName, customerCode: String
}
```

View Controller:

```
class dashboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

var properties =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)
var propertiesNew =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchAndReloadDataConnectedProperties()

    CollectionView.delegate = self
    CollectionView.dataSource = self
  }
  
  
  func fetchAndReloadDataConnectedProperties(){
    APICallerGET.shared.connectedPropertiesOfAccount(for: APICallerGET.shared.token!) { [self] (result, error) in
        
        switch result?.StatusCode {
        case 0:
            
           self.propertiesNew = result!
           self.properties = self.propertiesNew
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dashboardTableView.reloadData()
            }
        case 1:
            print("error")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return properties.Result?.count ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? dashboardCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}
    
    let currentPropertie = properties.Result![indexPath.item]
    
    cell.nameSurnameLabel?.text = currentPropertie.completeName
    
    cell.containerForCell.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(3)
    
    
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    return CGSize(width: 185, height: 50)
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's your issue? The CollectionView or the Web API Call?

Comment: @Larme hey man! , it's just that I don't know how to show the data in horizontal view in collectionView since I am used in tableView only and now this is my first try on CollectionViews and its different than tableView

Comment: I think you could just watch a few tutorials on Youtube to get it figured out. Search "UICollectionView Horizontal Layout"

Comment: @Michael the problem was that I wasn't reloading the tableView xD , Thanks though :)

Comment: @Larme If you see closely the fetchAndReloadDataConnectedProperties() is reloading a tableView not a collectionView and that was the small mistake :( , Thanks though Larme it's always a pleasure